# Replacing Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory with Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: azure-ad-msal

Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory seems to deprecated and my company is suggesting to migrate to use Microsoft.Identity.Client. I need to retrieve an access token from my AZURE KEY VAULT. May I know the replacement code by using Microsoft.Identity.Client. BACKGROUND: This is a .Net Framework 4.6.2 project

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    try
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,
                                            new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret));
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Bearer token acquisition needed to call KeyVault service failed");
        }
        else
        {
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        var ex = new Exception(string.Format("Authentication failed for {0}", ClientId), exp);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```